# Did I wire my receptacle and switch correctly?

Tags: electrical

I want a always on receptacle and a switched light

[image]

Comment: Looks right. With my OCD I'd probably change something a little, but that's a personal problem of mine. Is this a 20A circuit? If so, then did you run #12 conductors to the light?

Comment: Are both the light & receptacle in the same box? If not, you really should have the neutral running to the switch box as well. That's current code and allows you (or a future owner) to put in a less expensive smart switch that requires neutral instead of a more expensive one that doesn't require neutral (and can cause other general issues).

Comment: Reading more from others, I probably assumed too much. Like assuming that your neutral is actually paired with the hot in romex and traverses your switch's box. (Your outlet and switch are in boxes, right :)?) For electrical questions you should probably make a more precise drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Switch ground is missing.

Light ground is missing.

Depending on the type of branch circuit, neutral attachment between a light and a receptacle is sometimes not allowed.

If I found wiring like this in my own home, I would correct the switch and the light first, then check what's going on with the neutral continuity.

I'm also assuming the neutral isn't touching both sides of the receptacle even though the line crosses two different screws.

Comment: I see a light ground...

Comment: Switches often don't have or need a ground wire connection per se, they normally ground automatically when used with a properly grounded metal box.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your area has not yet adopted NEC2011 or later, (there are a few of those) the neutral wire has to come through the switch box, even if this switch does not use it. That's to allow for smart switches and motion sensors that need a neutral. Likewise the hot and neutral should be kept together in the same cable or conduit (even on NEC2008 or before, except for *switch loops* allowed under those codes - that this isn't.)

The switch needs a ground as well. The light ground going somewhere else is peculiar, and generally only done as a retrofit for old devices with no ground in the original wiring.

This is easily accomplished by bringing the cable with hot, neutral and ground from the receptacle to the switch box, and then on (with switched hot, after passing through the switch) to the light location.

Comment: Unless OP is using loose wires running different ways in the walls, I imagine this is a bad stick drawing, only showing connections, not paths.